# jquery hidden div not displayed on loading page

Tags: jquery, html, select, hide

I'm trying to show/hide divs depend on select.

The code below works fine but it does not work on loading page with the default selected value (opt3).

How can I get div id #opt3 diplayed on first load with jquery?

```
<body>

        <div>

        <p>

                <select name="routing-sel" id="routing">

                        <option value="opt1">opt1</option>

                        <option value="opt2">opt2</option>

                        <option value="opt3" selected>opt3</option>

                        <!-- the selected value will be dynamically generated by PHP-->

                </select>

                </p>

        </div>



        <div id="opt1" class="form" style="display:none">

                <p>opt1 selected</p>

        </div>

        <div id="opt2" class="form" style="display:none">

                <p>opt2 selected</p>

        </div>

        <div id="opt3" class="form" style="display:none">

                <p>opt3 selected</p>

        </div>



        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>



        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

                $('select#routing').change(function() {

                        $('.form').hide();

                        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();

                });

        });

        </script>

</body>
```

Comment: `$('#' + $('select#routing').val()).show();`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#' + $("#routing").val()).show(); // Show default chosen option on load

            $('select#routing').change(function() {

                    $('.form').hide();

                    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();

            });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/8zewxp7r/

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your document.ready to this. This will work..

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#' + $('select#routing').val()).show();

            $('select#routing').change(function() {

                    $('.form').hide();

                    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();

            });

    });
```